# Is there a way to write a regex that recognizes overlapping patterns? (any language)

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, overlapping-matches

I'm wondering if there is, for example, a way to write a regular expression that matches all of `("a.b", "b.c", "c.d")` in the string `"a.b.c.d"`.

I can only think of patterns like `"\w\.\w"` that match `"a.b"` and `"c.d"`, but not where the two overlap.

Comment: I don't think there's a language-agnostic way.

Comment: In general, the solutions for finding overlapping matches involved the way you call the matching function, not the regexp itself. You can't generally use the built-in "find all matches" operation, you need to use some other kind of loop.

Comment: E.g. loop over all the indexes in the input string, testing if the regexp matches starting at each index.

Comment: `(?=([a-z]\.[a-z]))` matches three empty strings with capture group 1 containing `"a.b"`, `"b.c"` and `"c.d"` respectively. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k3eDry/1)